# Can gitattributes filters remove or add files?

Tags: git, gitattributes, git-filter

[Git attributes](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#Keyword-Expansion) can be used to set up filters per file to make the content of the working directory be a transformed version of the repository content. I was wondering if this could be used to clean up the `.SRCINFO` files that have to be dealt with in [Archlinux' new AUR version 4](https://aur4.archlinux.org/).

Essentially, there are two files called `PKGBUILD` and `.SRCINFO` that both have to be stored in the repository. For my case it can be safely assumed that `.SRCINFO` is generated by running a program called `mksrcinfo` on the `PKGBUILD`. I want both to show up in the repository, but only `PKGBUILD` in my local tree.

How can I set up a filter pair so that

- *smudge* removes `.SRCINFO`, or even better does not create it to begin with and
- *clean* adds `.SRCINFO`, generated by running `mksrcinfo PKGBUILD`?